# Simple spreadsheet for Android

Tags: gratis, android, spreadsheet

I am looking for a simple spreadsheet app to use on my Android phone.

Desired features:

- Basic spreadsheet functionality, ie entering data in rows and columns, including properly formatted dates/times
- Simple formula, eg adding, sums, averages
- Sorting or filtering columns
- Importing and exporting data in a standard format, eg CSV
- Works offline
- Lightweight app preferred, ie not requiring much memory
- Free of charge

Answer (score 2):

These are the three best spreadsheet programs that I've found for Android:

1. [Microsoft Excel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel&hl=en_US)
2. [WPS Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng&hl=en)
3. [Google Sheets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets&hl=en)

I would definitely recommend installing all three of them to determine which one works best for your individual needs. **They all have every feature you mentioned**. I'm not sure if Microsoft Excel is free (I can't tell because I'm already subscribed to Office 365) but you should be able to see when you open it for the first time. I believe Microsoft went 100% fremium on Word, Excel, Outlook, and PowerPoint a while back, for Android that is. If I had to choose from the three I would definitely personally choose Excel. It's by far the most mature of the three programs.

I hope one of them works well for you!